# fullcalendar group identifier for a set of events

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I am creating a calendar that will include several groups of individuals for an on-call schedule.  The calendar will be read-only but the user can select 1 or more groups to display the people that are on-call for the month.

I need to be able to identify an individual that is on-call with the group that they are on-call for.  If fullcalendar could do subevents, that would be ideal so that the Parent Event is the name of the group and all of the members of the group are within the parent event.  But from what I have read that is not possible. The members can have all the same color but I need the name of the group on the calendar somehow.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

THanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use seperate eventsources and on different actions reload each event sources differently,
i.e.

- if the group is selected show the event source of the group in
  calander and show the names of group members seperately,
- and then on selecting a particular group member remove the previous event source and add the event source corresponding to the group member and rerender the calander
  Please refer the below link to know how to use event sources
  http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: Thank you for your instruction.  I can't work on this immediately because I need to work on another project.  But I will study thoroughly and will probably have more questions.  I am glad there is some solution.  All other searches seemed it was not possible.  Thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand by what you mean by 'show the names of group separately'.  I currently have checkboxes that show/hide a group.  When shown the group members are displayed on the calendar.  So each event is 1 week long with the name of the group member as the event title.  How is the event source of the group shown on the calendar?

Comment: are you aware of eventsource object in fullcalander io?
you can just remove and re insert any event sources at any DOM actions (like click,mouseover, selecting a particular group).
on doing so, use ajax to change the json feed of the event source and re-render the calander, look into full calander documentation to know about using eventsources

Comment: I am just beginning to learn about event sources.  The examples all use json feeds and would use an array for each event source that corresponds with the members of the group.